# Code to generate all possible combinations

Tags: java, optimization, combinations

If i have 3 apples and 2 buckets I could organize them as follows:

- 1 apple in bucket A and 2 apples in bucket B
- 2 apples in bucket A and 1 apple in bucket B
- 3 apples in bucket A and 0 apples in bucket B
- 3 apples in bucket B and 0 apples in bucket A

etc..

I am trying to cook up some kind of program that will generate such combinations for me when the number of apples can be any number and the number of buckets can also be any number. My gut tells me that there will be some recursion involved but, i can't even get started. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: search up permutation and you will find bunch examples

Comment: @Steve "Permutations" sounds wrong as they deal with the arrangement of *different* things. You can permute you apples as long as you want and nothing happens.

Comment: @maaartinus the real term for this question is actually combination, but there is no official name for that and you would find bunch unrelated posts, you will find lots permutation posts which offers 'combination' alternatives

Answer (score 1):

Yes, recursion can be used for this problem.

Hint to get you started:  If you have `M` apples and `N` buckets, then one subset of the solutions can be found by putting `m <= M` apples into the first bucket, and then finding all solutions to the subproblem with `(M - m)` apples and `N - 1` buckets.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can certainly use recursion and it would simplify things by holding context in the heap. But it's not strictly necessary.

Here's some (not very efficent and with a lot of stuff missing) psuedo code using interation to give you somewhere to start if you prefer this approach. The algorithm below looks a bit anti-intuitive but if you think it through you'll see it works. I've tried it out and it works perfectly so let me know if you get stuck and I'll post some working code. You might also like to try both the recursive and iterative versions and see which one makes more sense to you.

```
put all apples in first bucket    
while (true) {
    add the solution to the list        
    firstNonEmptyBucket = find first bucket with any apples;
    if (firstNonEmptyBucket is the last bucket)
        break - you are finished
    shift 1 apple from firstNonEmptyBucket to next bucket
    if (firstNonEmptyBucket is not the first bucket)
        shift all apples from firstNonEmptyBucket to previous bucket
}
```